# Customizing android NuPlayer for inclusion in Android app

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-build

### Question:

What is the suggested way to customize native components of Android for inclusion in an Android app? By "native components" I mean components for which the native source code is available in AOSP - but which use API's not exposed in the NDK documentation.

---

#### Details:

I want to use a simplified version of the Android media framework (actually, all I need is the NuPlayer to play an RTSP stream for my app). I know this sort of customization involves using the native code (frameworks/base/media) from AOSP, modifying what I need; and building this to generate the .so file as per my needs. I then do a `System.loadLibrary()` plus JNI.

My question is - what is the suggested way to do this?

I cannot use the NDK (rather, I am not supposed to use NDK) since many of the API's used in the media framework are not exposed to the NDK. But then, how do I build my modified media framework code? I do see `Android.mk` files in there. What do I use to build these?

Comment: I doubt, if you can build lib.so files without using NDK. As far as I know, you have to use the NDK compiler to build your own library to be used with other NDK apps.

Comment: That's what it looks like from [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/d/topic/android-ndk/gXvU1tYZb2U/discussion) on Android-NDK google group.

Comment: I changed your title to be NuPlayer specific

Answer (score 0):

Your question is self-contradictory: you want to *customize native components of Android*, without *use the NDK*. NDK stands for Native Development Kit: I have heard no one developing native components without using Native Development tools. And the NDK is the easiest one to use...

IMHO, your real problem lies in this statement: *I cannot use the NDK (rather, I am not supposed to use NDK)*. Here I ask: why?

Comment: Well that's the whole point: NDK is for using native code *within the scope of an app*. It can only use the APIs exposed by the NDK. On the other hand, the native components of the Android framework (like the media framework I want to use) are *outside the scope of an app*. The discussion thread on Android-NDK google group I linked to has more details on this.

Comment: Then I guess the only solution remaining for you is to get inspiration from android NuPlayer and write your own MediaPlayer in your app (java or c++). A colleague and I have imported and rebuilt android dbus stack in our app thanks to the ndk. We had to port a desktop app which uses dbus for daemon/client IPC. We tested it on a rooted device, it worked fine as a proof of concept. Now we are replacing dbus by a more android'ish IPC. But my point is: we met no big obstacle to embed dbus in our app; in the first place, as a proof of concept. Anyway I'll be interested of how you solved your issue.